# Change color of figure caption text

Tags: captions

In my code below, I wanted to change the color of the text for the table and figure caption.  I am using this:

```
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelfont={color=ocre,bf}]{caption}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\textcolor{ocre}{\bfseries\itshape\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textcolor{ocre}{\bfseries\itshape Fig.}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\textcolor{ocre}{\bfseries\itshape\arabic{table}}}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{\textcolor{ocre}{\bfseries\itshape Table}}
```

This is what I get as the output.

[image]

Can you tell me how to get the caption text the same color as the Fig.1.1 text?

Comment: Use font instead of labelfont.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do all your changes using options for the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font={color=ocre,bf},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={it}]{caption}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{Test figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In standard classes `book` and `report`, the `figure` and `table` counters are by default subordinated to the `chapter` counter; if you are using a class in which this is not the default, you can use

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithin{table}{chapter
```

so the counter will be subordinated and will reset each time `chapter` steps.

It is not a good idea,in general, to involve direct modifications of attributes like color in redefinitions of `\thefigure` (or `\thetable`), since then the changes will also appear in (most of the times) undesired locations, such as cross-references.