# Change label caption color of a single figure

Tags: floats, color, captions

Is it possible to change the caption color in a single figure without changing the color labels of other figures?

I have used this code [Change color of figure caption text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132611/change-color-of-figure-caption-text) but every figure is changing its color. I want to do it for only one figure.

My code is mainlyfrom [Change color of figure caption text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132611/change-color-of-figure-caption-text)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelfont={color=red}]{caption}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{Test figure A}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
B
\caption{Test figure B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post what you've tried?

Comment: Do you want to change only color of caption or also the Figure and number? For 1st case, `\caption[Test figure A]{\textcolor{red}{Test figure A}}` should work.

Comment: Both the caption and the number, but I mostly care about the number (with Fig.).

Comment: To change everything, you can try `{\color{red}\caption{text}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my point of view `\captionsetup{labelfont={color=blue}}` etc. in the local environment is sufficient:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont={color=red}]{caption}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{labelfont={color=blue}}
A
\caption{Test figure A}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
B
\caption{Test figure B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Glad that removed my answer before you answer this... Already feel somehow stupid (+1 already)

Comment: @koleygr: Thanks, no need to feel stupid, however. Good packages (and `caption` is a very good one, in my point of view) provide such local group-aware `\...setup` like macro, that simplifies customization...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a start.  For the caption itself, you could do as the comments suggest and place a `\textcolor` in the `\caption` argument.  The number (like "1.2" is contained in `\thefigure`, while the descriptor word "Figure" is kept in `\figurename`.

kolygr correctly points out that I don't really need to renew `\thefigure`, because the color change applied before `\figurename` will carry through.  I will leave the code as is though, in case one gets ideas about changing `\figurename` and `\thefigure` to two separate colors.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{caption}
\let\svthefigure\thefigure
\let\svfigurename\figurename
\newcommand\figcolor[1]{%
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\bfseries\sffamily\color{#1}\svthefigure}
  \renewcommand\figurename{\bfseries\sffamily\color{#1}\svfigurename}
}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{Test figure A}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\figcolor{blue}
\centering
B
\caption{Test figure B}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
B
\caption{Test figure B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

kolygr **also points out** that the above code will retain the color in `\ref` attributes.  That can be avoided by storing the figure markup in a separate markup macro, and `\protect`ing it so that the expansion (with color) doesn't get written to the `aux` file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{caption}
\let\svthefigure\thefigure
\let\svfigurename\figurename
\renewcommand\thefigure{\protect\myfigmarkup\svthefigure}
\renewcommand\figurename{\protect\myfigmarkup\svfigurename}
\let\myfigmarkup\relax
\newcommand\figcolor[1]{%
  \def\myfigmarkup{\bfseries\sffamily\color{#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
In Figure~\ref{fg1.2}...

\chapter{Test chapter}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{Test figure A}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\figcolor{blue}
\centering
B
\caption{Test figure B}
\label{fg1.2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
B
\caption{Test figure B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may replace `\color` by `\textcolor` or a similar change because the color will be maintained in a possible reference.... (+1... I learn something new again from you!)

Comment: I didn't thought about that... I just tested with a previous version of mine by adding "Figure~\ref{label} is red" and the text "is red" was red too... So, you need to enclose `\color` command inside braces or use `\textcolor` instead to avoid the color be maintained after a possible reference (that is also another problem if the op want it in black and not colored])

Comment: @koleygr I see.  Let me think on that more.

Comment: @koleygr Thank you again for pointing that out.  I added an addendum to address it, depending on what the OP wants.

Comment: Just realized how close was my code to yours and deleted my answer... I didn't mentioned that your `\svthefigure` was defined by a \let command like mine.... I thought it had to do with something internal to the figure and tried to learn from it... But finally my answer had nothing more to offer than yours and deleted

Comment: Very nice approach... I used `\protect` sometimes but never really understood that about the aux file... Will upvote your next answer too :P... (Good night)